# XAML Node Stream: Missing StartObject before StartMember

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemtemplate

I am getting the following Exception with my Item Templates.[image]

I have designed my UI using WPF application . and it is vsix project. any ideas on this.

Comment: This is terrible. I see this issue on one customer's side, Win 7. Any fix?

Comment: This happens for me in Windows 7 when the program is compiled for Windows 8.